# UWP Window Placement

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am creating a .net UWP application in Visual Studio 2015 RC.  I successfully set the Window size by using the following code:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(New Size(width, height))
```

What I would like is to be able to set the preferred window position on the screen (e.g. centred) but cannot find a way to set this in code.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the Windows position on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082799/how-can-i-set-the-windows-position-on-startup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything obvious. Apps can request a specific size but not position for their views.