# Is there a way to resize and center a UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am writing a small UWP app which is going to be launched from another app (the main app). I am hoping to decrease the window size of the UWP app.

I was able to change the window size by adding the code commented below into the App constructor. But I couldn't figure out how to make the UWP app center screen after I changed the window size. Any advices on making the UWP center screen is appreciated.

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(600, 400); //added code
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize; //added code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to resize and center a UWP app?

No, I am afraid there is no API to set the positon of the UWP window:

[[UWP] Change the position of window close proximity to the right edge of the screen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/186c17bb-3cdf-4ea1-8e8b-90050ee60c44/uwp-change-the-position-of-window-close-proximity-to-the-right-edge-of-the-screen?forum=wpdevelop)

[UWP Window Placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048576/uwp-window-placement)

[How can I set the Windows position on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082799/how-can-i-set-the-windows-position-on-startup)

Comment: Thanks for answering!